# Django static path of the image is not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load the static path of the image which is not working but the static path of the css files are working perfectly . I have tried every different way but still getting 404

this is i am trying to access the image which is inside the folder of `ip` in static **folder**

```
            <div class="col-auto">
              <img src="{% static 'ip/best.png' %}"/>
            </div>
```

I have load the static block above

```
{% load static %}
```

and the settings.py configuraion of static url

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

Comment: Show us one of the working static tags that uses a css file, and show us the full directory path where the png and css files are located.

Comment: Did you run the collectstatic manage.py command? `manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: @JohnGordon {% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}

Comment: @sytech yes i have done this

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a media file so you need to add this to the project settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
```

you can add the folder to it and refer to it

Comment: where is the ip folder located?

Comment: inside the static folder

Comment: is the static folder inside the application folder?

Comment: Is `static` folder it inside the `app` folder?

Comment: main folder of the project
  -- static folder
      -- ip folder
           --image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224561/discussion-between-a-k-and-tayyab-gulsher-vohra).